# Why does getElementById applied to the same id returns a different object after modifying its parent with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have just noticed that document.getElementById("one_id") returns different objects before and after modifying its parent by using its innerHTML property.

This happens in every single browser I have tested. Why is that? What is the reason?

Here is an example so you can test and see by yourself:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        function test()
        {
            var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
            myDiv.id = "myDivID";

            var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            bodyTag.appendChild(myDiv);

            var myDivIDBeforeAdding = document.getElementById("myDivID");
            bodyTag.innerHTML += "something added";
            var myDivIDAfterAdding = document.getElementById("myDivID");

            if (myDivIDBeforeAdding != myDivIDAfterAdding) //This is always true!
            {
                bodyTag.innerHTML += "<br />myDivIDBeforeAdding = " + myDivIDBeforeAdding;
                bodyTag.innerHTML += "<br />myDivIDAfterAdding = " + myDivIDAfterAdding;
                bodyTag.innerHTML += "<br />myDivIDBeforeAdding and myDivIDAfterAdding are different!!!";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="test();">
</body>
```

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,

Joan

Comment: What did you get different, I checked it out and most of the stuff are sasme...

Comment: Pay attention to the if clause. It is true every time, so it means the objects stored in each variable are different.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the way that browsers implement `innerHTML`. A straightforward implementation would parse the incoming value, build a new DOM fragment using that as a blueprint and then remove (detach from the DOM) the old children of `bodyTag` and attach the new fragment. This is in fact what [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) on the subject:

> Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and
>   assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.

In such a scenario, inspecting the "before" and "after" DOM nodes would tell you they are identical twins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my real project, what I am trying to do is to avoid using too many document.getElementById() calls. So my idea is to call it just once and store it in a variable to use it all around my script. But this method doesn't seem to work since the variable doesn't point to the same object anymore after modifying its parent by innerHTML. Do you have any suggestion regarding this, please? (I am afraid that I will have to end updating that variable every time I use innerHTML in the parent).

Comment: Why are you afraid? Unless your page runs slowly and you have traced the problem to `getElementById` overhead (a purely hypothetical scenario) then why are you bent on avoiding it?

Comment: It is because I am developing a Javascript game engine and I try to optimize the code as much as possible everywhere I am able to.

Comment: @jalbam: That's a noble goal, but then perhaps it would be faster to do certain manipulations manually instead of using `innerHTML`. In any case you should always optimize after having concrete benchmark results in hand.